# Sails.js waterline destroy "lower or equal" criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to use the `destroy` method with a lower than in the request, and I can't make it to work.

Although, the `find` method returns some content with the exact same parameters.

```
Cars.find({userId: params.userId, accessDate: { '<=': new Date() }}, function (err, found) {
    console.log(found); //Returns an array with multiple entries.
}); 

Cars.destroy({userId: params.userId, accessDate: { '<=': new Date() }}); //Does nothing, the entries are not destroyed.
```

This is the content in my database returned by the first request:

```
[ { userId: '563c1c37be1ed48e7f8c6ada',
    accessDate: '2015-11-07T21:36:13.169Z',
    id: '563e60bd19667c52bd831182' },
  { userId: '563c1c37be1ed48e7f8c6ada',
    accessDate: '2015-11-10T05:04:01.850Z',
    id: '56416cb140112987ce6ec049' },
  { userId: '563c1c37be1ed48e7f8c6ada',
    accessDate: '2015-11-12T03:59:36.519Z',
    id: '5644009851503b42e589ecf1' } ]
```

Am I wrong somewhere? What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Cars.find({userId: params.userId, accessDate: { '<=': new Date() }})
    .exec(function (err, found) {

    });

    Cars.destroy({userId: params.userId, accessDate: { '<=': new Date() }})
    .exec(function (err) {

    });
```

Hope helpful

Comment: Hmmm... that is weird! I thought the callback wasn't required. But yes, this works with a callback! Thanks